# attach files to SQL operation studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, windows

I have .MDF and .LDF files created by SQL Server. I'm trying to attach them to my SQL operations studio. I have put files in var/opt/mssql/data but the operation studio does not show the files even after refreshing or disconnecting.  Is there any other ways to attach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases can be attached using a T-SQL query. Execute  [`CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) from a query window, specifying the desired database name along with the existing file paths with the `FILENAME` clause. For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE YourDatabase
    ON (FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/yourdb.mdf')   
    LOG ON (FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/yourdb_log.ldf')   
  FOR ATTACH;
```

This method can be used with SQL Operations Studio, SQL Server Management Studio, SQLCMD, mssql_cli, or any tool that can run SQL queries.